# Python script to insert data into multiple SQL tables

Tags: python, sql

For our semester project we need to insert data from a stream that's updated every 3,5s into 2 separate SQL tables and this has to be done with a Python script.

The Idea is to have 2 rooms (Office, Server) that each have a combined temperature and humidity sensor while the server room has a smoke detector too.

The data is send from a Arduino over USB and the data stream looks like this:

> Server:61.20,22.70,221.00Office:64.00,23.00

The Python script I've managed to cobble together looks like this:

```
import serial
import time
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host        ="127.0.0.1",
        user        ="root",
        password    ="",
        database    ="messwerte"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

device = 'COM3' 
try:
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600) 
except: 
  print("Error: {}".format()),device;    

while True:
    try:
      time.sleep(2)
      data = arduino.readline() 
      print.data
      pieces = data.split(" ") 
      try:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO dht11serial (humidity,temperature,CO2) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (pieces[0],pieces[1],pieces[2]))
        mydb.commit()
        mycursor.close()  
      except mysql.connector.IntegrityError as err:
        print("Error: {}".format(err))
    except:
      print("Error: {}".format(err))
```

Now I would need to insert the values for each room into a SQL table that corresponds to that room but how could I manage that?

Please keep in mind that I have actually no idea what I'm doing. It's my very first time doing anything with Python or SQL.

Comment: I don't think having separate tables for every room is good DB design in the first place. And in addition you have another one - `dht11serial` where you store some data without location info whatsoever.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions on a better DB design, as said I'm completely new to this and hoping for any input to make it work.

The code is just something I put together and tried with a previous iteration of our project so actually none of the tables and DB's are used now.

Answer (score 1):

I created this script based on the data stream you posted. I used the same configuration for the arduino connection. The script will generate the database file and the two tables if they do not exists, not need to worry about losing data each time you run the script.

It should work right away (hope so), if not then you only need to adjust the data stream, i put some comments in the code to help you out. Basically, you just need to create two tables inside the same database and same the data twice.

I changed SQL motor to sqlite3, since data will be stored local.

Put the code inside a .py file and run it! Tell me if it works.

```
import serial
import time
import sqlite3


#Database file is stored in the same folder where script is located.
#File will created itself if not exists
conn = sqlite3.connect("./data.sqlite3")

cursor = conn.cursor()


#Server table inside data.sqlite3
server = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS server (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    humidity VARCHAR(255),
    temperature VARCHAR(255),
    CO2 VARCHAR(255))"""

#Office table inside data.sqlite3
office = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS office (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    humidity VARCHAR(255),
    temperature VARCHAR(255),
    CO2 VARCHAR(255))"""


#Creates tables inside database, nothing will happen if tables already exists
cursor.execute(server)
#You can comment out these lines, use them only if you are creating a new file
cursor.execute(office)

conn.commit()

#Arduino conection
#App makes no sense without this, allow it to crash if there is no connection.
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600) 


#Forever 
while True:

    #Catching error inside a try-except loop will keep these going forever
    #Even if arduino connection gets lost
    #Rest 3.5 each loop
    time.sleep(3.5)

    try:

        #Server:61.20,22.70,221.00Office:64.00,23.00,220.00
        data = arduino.readline() 

        #Remove Server: and Office: from data string
        #You need to leave a comma where Office: is located to separate both values
        cleaned_data = data.replace("Server:","").replace("Office:",",")
        
        #Cleaned data looks like this: 61.20,22.70,221.00,64.00,23.00,220.00
        #We know first 3 values are from server, last 3 are from office
        #Split the string in elements using commas
        pieces = cleaned_data.split(",") 

        #[ 61.20, 22.70, 221.00, 64.00, 23.00, 220.00 ]
        print(pieces)
      
        #Send data to server table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO server (humidity,temperature,CO2) VALUES (?,?,?)",(pieces[0],pieces[1],pieces[2]))

        #Send data to office table
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO office (humidity,temperature,CO2) VALUES (?,?,?)",(pieces[3],pieces[4],pieces[5]))
        
        #Write to database confirmation
        conn.commit()

        #There is no need to close connection to database  

    #Prints out what caused the error       
    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
```

Comment: looks awesome, I'll try that asap this evening.

Just one question, that bit at the start of my code where that "mydb = mysql.connector.connect(" bit isn't needed anymore or how does it work now?

Comment: I change mySQL motor for SQLite3

Same instructions but SQLite3 is for creating local databases inside a file that you can move with your USB :P

Comment: thank you and it works perfectly fine but the projects goal is to display the data from the mySQL DB on a Webpage.

Comment: It wont take you much time. Just use flask :) , from my perspective, create another app with a function to retrieve data from the database file. Then use Flask to render a dinamic webpage with the data you extracted.

This webpage will work localy or LAN. If you want external access you need to host it on a server, or heroku.